# A bug in tableView leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've run into a strange bug in **leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt** method.
I'm setting image and title properties for UIContextualAction.
And when I set the title over 6 characters it has odd behavior when on the first swipe the gap between image and title is too small. And on second and next swipes it becomes normal. Take a look at 2 gifs I've attached:

[7 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCaoR.gif)

[6 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWv4f.gif)

My code is pretty simple:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "1234567") { (_, _, _) in }
    action.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}
```

I've run it on Xcode 10.0 on multiple simulators (iPhone 5 SE, iPhone 7, iPhone X) and on one real device (iPhone 7)

Any thoughts on how to fix that?